# For Loop value assign with multiple String - java

Tags: java, for-loop

below are the For Loop

```
//Declare 5 String variable
String p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;

for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
    String pno = driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id='body']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td")).getText();
    p1 = pno;
}
```

my question

while executing the First row (row =1) it should be assign that value in p1 variable

While executing the Second row (row = 2) it should be assign that value in p2 variable
, vice-versa

how could possible to assign the each row value with separate variable in java

Comment: Give our answers some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for an `array` or `ArrayList`

```
//in your loop where i is iterator variable
arr[i] = someNewValue;
```

or if you are not sure how many elements

```
arrayList.add(someNewValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ArrayList` if you want to dynamic sized collection. i.e when you don't know the exact size you would need

```
ArrayList<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
    String pno = driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//*[@id='body']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td")).getText();
    p.add(pno);
}
```

If you know the *exact size*, then String `Array` would be sufficient. I see that you have *hardcoded* the max value conditional statement in your `for` loop. then, it is evident that you know the exact size you need. Here, you can go for String array as well.

```
String[] p = new String[5]; // length is 5
for (int row = 1,count=0; row <= 5; row++,count++) {
    String pno = driver.findElement(
                 By.xpath("//*[@id='body']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td")).getText();
    p[count] = pno;
}
```

Hope you understand now

Comment: you need count++ right?

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare 5 String variable
String p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;

String[] pArray = new String[5]; // create an array to store values

for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
    String pno = driver.findElement(
        By.xpath("//*[@id='body']/table/tbody/tr[" + row + "]/td")).getText();
    pArray[row - 1] = pno; // store value to an array
}

// put the values in the array to the Strings originally created
p1 = pArray[0];
p2 = pArray[1];
p3 = pArray[2];
p4 = pArray[3];
p5 = pArray[4];
```